# Google Container Registry Broken (Push stucked)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've been trying to push my docker image to Google Container Registry and it is always getting stucked.

```
gcloud docker push gcr.io/projectID/ImageName
```

Authentication is OK but it is stucked always

```
6f9c01afe229: Pushing [>                                                  ] 524.3 kB/62.14 MB
```

It is not a connection or network problem as I've tried from different networks.

---

As en alternative I am pushing to a Google Storage bucket and it is working fine:

```
gcloud docker push b.gcr.io/your-bucket/ImageName
```

In any case I'd like to use Google Container Registry so please if someone experienced the same issue please share.

Comment: Was `b.gcr.io` in your first command a typo?  Have you tried just `gcr.io`?

Comment: Yes sorry it was just a typo, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try just gcr.io.

Generally, projectID is used with gcr.io and bucketName is used with b.gcr.io.

This link has more detailed information about pushing image to gcr:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing

Comment: Thanks, it was just a typo, the problem is with the gcr.io host

Comment: We will follow up and try to fix the issue. To investigate the real problem, we need your projectId to get some log. Can you email your projectId to gcr-contact@google.com? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Mac? If so, can you first try to restart docker machine (docker-machine restart default)? Some Mac users have seen this kind of "hang" behavior before.